# Define and reuse MVEL function

Tags: java, function, embedding, evaluation, mvel

Is it possible to define some custom precompiled function with MVEL and use one in another compiled expressions?
If I try the following:

```
MVEL.compileExpression("function hello() { System.out.println(\"Hello!\"); hello(); return x * y;");
```

I get `Exception in thread "main" [Error: duplicate function: hello]` when try to execure it second time.

It looks like I should declare the function not at the expression itself, but some kind of context. I played with ParsedContext for a while, but always got `Exception in thread "main" [Error: unable to access property (null parent): hello]`.

Internet is full of tutorials that cover different MVEL language usage topics, but such embedding topics a very poorly documented. Could you please give me some clue what I'm doing wrong?

P.S. I don't want to execute some function from Java. I need to define them dynamically with MVEL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bit trickier than some common use-cases, although it is possible.

Fundamentally, what you need to do is create a script which defines your functions, like so:

```
VariableResolverFactory functionFactory = new MapVariableResolverFactory();
MVEL.eval("def foo() { System.out.println("foo"); }; def bar() { System.out.println("bar") };", functionFactory);
```

Then, what you do is back-chain this factory to any expression you run:

```
VariableResolverFactory myVarFactory = new MapVariableResolverFactory();
myVarFactory.setNextFactory(functionFactory);

Serializable s = MVEL.compileExpression("foo(); bar();");

MVEL.executeExpression(s, myVarFactory);
```

Functions are recorded as references on the variable table, so you can use regular variable factory back-chaining to share them in MVEL.

Note: You shouldn't re-share 'myVarFactory'. You want to create a new one every time. You only want to recycle 'functionFactory' and back-chain it to the per-run factories as shown above. Otherwise you'll end up sharing local var state between executions -- and that's not thread-safe

Comment: The example you provided gives me NullPointerException at second line. What can be the cause? I have MVEL 2.0.19 and run your example in the clean main() method.

Comment: All fixed. I also added an additional disclaimer.

Comment: I mean NPE at `MVEL.eval("def foo() { System.out.println(\"foo\"); }; def bar() { System.out.println(\"bar\") };", functionFactory);`. The second line of the program at all!

Comment: I have switched to MVEL 2.1.0.drools16 and now the example works OK. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MikeBrock thanks for taking the time to post your solution here, this   just saved me a lot of API sleuthing time.  Although I would like to point out that, when used in assignment expressions, the functions only successfully execute beyond the first call if the expression end in a semi-colon.  This is reasonable, but worth noting in case anyone runs across it.

Comment: nevermind the bit about the semicolon, it was an error on my part.  need to go to bed...